# What does add_index with multiple values do in a Rails migration?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, ruby-on-rails-3, indexing, migration

I've read through [this](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html) and looked at [this](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Migration.html), but I'm none-the-wiser:

**What exactly does this do (as opposed to passing in a single column name) and what is the advantage?**

```
add_index :resources, [:one, :two]
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It adds a multi-column index on columns `one` and `two` in `resources` table.

The statement:

```
add_index :resources, [:one, :two], name: 'index_resources_one_two'
```

is equivalent to:

```
create index index_resources_one_two on resources(one, two)
```

Passing in a single column would only create index on that column only. For example the following line:

```
add_index :resources, :one, name: 'index_resources_one'
```

is equivalent to:

```
create index index_resources_one on resources(one)
```

The advantage of multi-column index is that it helps when you have a query with conditions on those multiple columns.

With multi-column index the query is worked on a smaller subset of data as compared to single column index when the query contains conditions on those multiple columns.

Say for example our resources table contains the following rows:

```
one, two 
 1,   1
 1,   1
 1,   3
 1,   4
```

The following query:

```
select * from resources where one = 1 and two = 1;
```

would only have to work on the following two rows if a multi-column index is defined:

```
one, two 
 1,   1
 1,   1
```

But, without the multi-column index, say for example there is an index on only `one` then the query would have to work on all the rows with `one` equal to `1` which is four rows.